# Different behavior while reading DataFrame from parquet using CLI Versus executable on same environment

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller, parquet, pyarrow

Please consider following program as [Minimal Reproducible Example -MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow
from pyarrow import parquet

def foo():
    print(pyarrow.__file__)
    print('version:',pyarrow.cpp_version)
    print('-----------------------------------------------------')
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B':['dummy']*3})
    print('Orignal DataFrame:\n', df)
    print('-----------------------------------------------------')
    _table = pyarrow.Table.from_pandas(df)
    parquet.write_table(_table, 'foo')
    _table = parquet.read_table('foo', columns=[])    #passing empty list to columns arg
    df = _table.to_pandas()
    print('After reading from file with columns=[]:\n', df)
    print('-----------------------------------------------------')
    print('Not passing [] to columns parameter')
    _table = parquet.read_table('foo')                #Not passing any list
    df = _table.to_pandas()
    print(df)
    print('-----------------------------------------------------')
    x = input('press any key to exit: ')

if __name__=='__main__':
    foo()
```

When I run it from console/IDE, it reads the entire data for `columns=[]`:

```py
(env) D:\foo>python foo.py
D:\foo\env\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\__init__.py
version: 3.0.0
-----------------------------------------------------
Orignal DataFrame:
    A      B
0  1  dummy
1  2  dummy
2  3  dummy
-----------------------------------------------------
After reading from file with columns=[]:
    A      B
0  1  dummy
1  2  dummy
2  3  dummy
-----------------------------------------------------
Not passing [] to columns parameter
   A      B
0  1  dummy
1  2  dummy
2  3  dummy
-----------------------------------------------------
press any key to exit:
```

But When I run it from executable created using Pyinstaller, *it reads no data for `columns=[]`*:

```py
E:\foo\dist\foo\pyarrow\__init__.pyc
version: 3.0.0
-----------------------------------------------------
Orignal DataFrame:
    A      B
0  1  dummy
1  2  dummy
2  3  dummy
-----------------------------------------------------
After reading from file with columns=[]:
 Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2]
-----------------------------------------------------
Not passing [] to columns parameter
   A      B
0  1  dummy
1  2  dummy
2  3  dummy
-----------------------------------------------------
press any key to exit:
```

As you can see passing `columns=[]` gives empty dataframe in executable file but this behavior is not there while running the python file directly, and I'm not sure why there is this two different behavior for the same code in the same environment.

Looking at docstring of `parquet.read_table` in [source code at GitHub](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/python/pyarrow/parquet.py#L1796):

> `columns: list` 
> If not None, only these columns will be read from the file. A column
> name may be a prefix of a nested field, e.g. 'a' will select 'a.b',
> 'a.c', and 'a.d.e'.

The read_table further calls [`dataset.read`](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/python/pyarrow/parquet.py#L1703) that calls [`_dataset.to_table`](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/python/pyarrow/_dataset.pyx#L453) which returns call to [`self.scanner`](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/python/pyarrow/_dataset.pyx#L372) which then returns call to static method [`from_dataset`](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/python/pyarrow/_dataset.pyx#L2934) of `Scanner` class.

Everywhere, `None` has been used as default value to `columns` parameter, if `None` and `[]` are directly converted to Boolean in python, both of them will indeed be `False`, but if `[]` is checked against `None`, then it will be `False`, but it is nowhere mentioned should it fetch all the columns for `columns=[]` because it evaluates to be `False` for Boolean value, or should it read no columns at all since the list is empty.

But why the behavior is different while running it from the Command line/IDE, than to running it from the executable created using Pyinstaller for the same version of Pyarrow?

The environment I'm on:

- Python Version: 3.7.6
- Pyinstaller Verson: 4.2
- Pyarrow Version: 3.0.0
- Windows 10 64 bit OS

Here is the spec file for your reference if you want to give it a try (*You need to change `pathex` parameter*):

**foo.spec**

```py
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys ; sys.setrecursionlimit(sys.getrecursionlimit() * 5)
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['foo.py'],
             pathex=['D:\\foo'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='foo',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='foo')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credit to @U12-Forward for assisting me in debugging the issue.

After a bit of research and debugging, and exploring the library program files, I found that pyarrow uses `_ParquetDatasetV2` and `ParquetDataset` functions which are essentially two different functions that reads the data from parquet file, `_ParquetDatasetV2` is used as `legacy_mode`, even though these functions are defined in pyarrow.parquet module, they are coming from `Dataset` module of pyarrow, which was missing in the executable created using Pyinstaller.

When I added `pyarrow.Dataset` as hidden imports and created the build, the exe was raising `ModuleNotFoundError` on execution due to several missing dependencies used by `Dataset` module. In order to resolve it, I added all `.py` files from the environment to the hidden imports and created the build again, finally it worked, by it worked, what I mean is I was able to observe the same behavior in both the environments.

The modified `spec` file looks like this after modification:

```py
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys ; sys.setrecursionlimit(sys.getrecursionlimit() * 5)
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['foo.py'],
             pathex=['D:\\foo'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['pyarrow.benchmark', 'pyarrow.cffi', 'pyarrow.compat', 'pyarrow.compute', 'pyarrow.csv', 'pyarrow.cuda', 'pyarrow.dataset', 'pyarrow.feather', 'pyarrow.filesystem', 'pyarrow.flight', 'pyarrow.fs', 'pyarrow.hdfs', 'pyarrow.ipc', 'pyarrow.json', 'pyarrow.jvm', 'pyarrow.orc', 'pyarrow.pandas_compat', 'pyarrow.parquet', 'pyarrow.plasma', 'pyarrow.serialization', 'pyarrow.types', 'pyarrow.util', 'pyarrow._generated_version', 'pyarrow.__init__'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='foo',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='foo')
```

Also, to create the build, I included the path of the virtual environment using `--paths` argument:

```py
pyinstaller --path D:\foo\env\Lib\site-packages foo.spec
```

Here is execution after following above mentioned steps:

```py
E:\foo\dist\foo\pyarrow\__init__.pyc
version: 3.0.0
-----------------------------------------------------
Orignal DataFrame:
    A      B
0  1  dummy
1  2  dummy
2  3  dummy
-----------------------------------------------------
After reading from file with columns=[]:
    A      B
0  1  dummy
1  2  dummy
2  3  dummy
-----------------------------------------------------
Not passing [] to columns parameter
   A      B
0  1  dummy
1  2  dummy
2  3  dummy
-----------------------------------------------------
press any key to exit:
```

It is true that it is nowhere mentioned the desired behavior for `columns=[]`, but looking at [ARROW-13436 opened in pyarrow](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-13436) by @Pace, it seems that the desired behavior for `columns=[]` is to read no data columns at all, but its not an official conformation, so it is possibly a bug in pyarrow 3.0.0 itself.

Answer (score 2):

The pyarrow documentation for `pyarrow.parquet.read_table` is probably unclear.  I've raised [ARROW-13436](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-13436) to clarify this.

From some testing it seems that the behavior changed at some point from no columns to all columns and then changed back (in 4.0) to no columns.  I believe no columns is the correct behavior.

So my guess is that your executable is using a different version of pyarrow than your IDE.  You can usually confirm this by running...

```
import pyarrow
print(pyarrow.__file__)
print(pyarrow.cpp_version)
```

...on both environments and then comparing the results.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm using *pyarrow 3.0.0* on both the environments, anyways, I'll print it and add that too in the question.

Comment: I have updated the question with those details.

Answer (score 1):

### After commenting with @ThePyGuy (the OP), the reason was found.

The reason is that when he ran it on the IDE, he ran it inside an environment, whereas when he ran it on the command line, it was outside the environment. And the DLL files where different. So the fix was to copy the pyarrow package to to outside the environment and it gave the same result.

Comment: No dll files are same, they are not different. And just copying the library program files is not solution, it needs to be done from pyinstaller while creating executable